# QT Creator Drop Down menu empty

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator

I have installed recently QT5 along with QT Creator 2.7.0 in my Ubuntu16 machine.
From the first moment I started to use QT Creator I noticed this problem, I can see correctly the menu bar with all the voices "File,Edit,Build,Debug,Analyze,Tools,Window,Help", my problem is that whenever I click on one of these menus the drop down menu is completely blank and doesn't display the all the options in it.

I am wondering if someone already had the same issue as me and what was the solution in your case.
Many thanks in advance to all for the help.

Attached an image that shows the problem described.

[image]

Comment: It definitely looks fishy, the menus shouldn't be so cramped.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider to upgrade to a more recent version. Qt Creator is at version 4.1 right now and 4.2 is close.

Answer (score 0):

resolved installing from apt qtcreator (version 3.5.2) and qt5-default.